# How to change font color based on background color using reactJs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have dynamic background of my container it will change by User so I need to set text color based of background color eg, I set black background of my container then i need to set white color for text, 
I am using ReactJs and material UI library for my App, please suggest some good path.

Comment: you can use styled components so in that way you can pass the props. based on the user selection the color will be applied. I will add a sample codesandbox snippet you can check give me some time

Comment: the javascript example is here.. but i want same in reactjs I am very new in React http://jsfiddle.net/2VTnZ/2/

Comment: give me sometime i was building sample one for a div

Comment: i have added the code and codepen link, happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the below sample code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DynamicContainer from "./style";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [bgColor, setBGColor] = useState("#422DAD");
  const [textColor, setTextColor] = useState("rgb(99,99,100)");

  function hexToRgb(hex) {
    // Expand shorthand form (e.g. "03F") to full form (e.g. "0033FF")
    var shorthandRegex = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
    hex = hex.replace(shorthandRegex, function(m, r, g, b) {
      return r + r + g + g + b + b;
    });

    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result
      ? {
          r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
          g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
          b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
        }
      : null;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let { r, g, b } = hexToRgb(bgColor);
    let targetColor = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
    var colors = targetColor.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    var brightness = 1;

    var R = colors[1];
    var G = colors[2];
    var B = colors[3];

    var ir = Math.floor((255 - R) * brightness);
    var ig = Math.floor((255 - G) * brightness);
    var ib = Math.floor((255 - B) * brightness);
    setTextColor(`rgb(${ir}, ${ig}, ${ib})`);
  }, [bgColor]);

  const handleBgChange = e => {
    setBGColor(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <DynamicContainer bgColor={bgColor} textColor={textColor}>
        Hello World!
      </DynamicContainer>
      <p>Choose Background color</p>
      <input type="color" value={bgColor} onChange={handleBgChange} />
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

here is the upadted codesandbox

check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/59193701-so-i0uy7)

Comment: Thanks for your quick solution.. But my requirement is different i want to set font color automatic based on background color, Just like this sample.. http://jsfiddle.net/2VTnZ/2/ , This is example I want it in ReactJs

Comment: @NitinShinde i have updated the codesandbox and it works as per your comments, happy coding :)

Comment: @NitinShinde Cool , Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

page:

```
<div className="divao">
   <span className="textao">UAU</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.divao{
   background: #000;
}
.textao{
   color: #FFF;
   mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
}
```

with this code the color of the .textao class automatically changes.