# How to read the background color and calculate a contrast front color in a React function component?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to read the background color from within a React function component (a nav header).

The issue is that an element of my site changes the background color based on an event. When this happens the font text can become unreadable (not enough contrast).

A part of my problem may be solved in the linked thread, but I don't know how to read the status. I have an SCSS import for the function, but the background is defined globally.

While I am at it: Is there an ideal contrast between font color and background color?

[How to change font color based on background color using reactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193701/how-to-change-font-color-based-on-background-color-using-reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you are changing the background color now, is it limited to some pre-defined colors or not but if it's pre-defined I would create color theme classes in CSS and assign the proper theme to the root or body of the page when it has to change. Then by using CSS specificity I would overwrite the text color through the website.

```
.darkGrayTheme {
   background-color: #5d5b5b;
}

 .lightGrayTheme {
   background-color: #ccc;
}

 // in other CSS file
 .darkGrayTheme .myCustomWidget {
   color: #FFF;
 }

 .lightGrayTheme .myCustomWidget {
   color: #ddd;
 }
```

if the background color can be any colors, I would group all possible colors by creating a map of color theme to group of color-range that can share a common text color and then follow above CSS color theme all over the application.

More info about [color theme creation](https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-theme-creation)

---

**Update based on the comment:**

if it's pre-defined and will be using as props, I would suggest to set the theme as a context at top level component and be able to access the theme object in any child components.

Example from [React hook documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

```
const themes = {
  light: {
    foreground: "#000000",
    background: "#eeeeee"
  },
  dark: {
    foreground: "#ffffff",
    background: "#222222"
  }
};

const ThemeContext = React.createContext(themes.light);

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={themes.dark}>
      <Toolbar />
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Toolbar(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ThemedButton />
    </div>
  );
}

function ThemedButton() {
  const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
    <button style={{ background: theme.background, color: theme.foreground }}>
      I am styled by theme context!
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: it's predefined and it seems I have to do it via props. I thought you could read the current bg color via DOM.

Comment: @wishi I updated the answer, I believe it's going to answer your question.